# MongoDB bulk API: Finding out whch bulk updates matched

Tags: mongodb, bulkupdate

I'm doing multiple updates in a single bulk. Note: they are updates, not upserts. The problem doesn't allow it. Is there a way to find out which commands form the bulk matched (or didn't)?

From what I saw in the manual, you can only find the number of matches from BulkWriteResult, not which one matched, but I thought I'd ask anyway. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BulkWriteResult` doesn't contain this information and, as of MongoDB 2.6.3, there's no way to obtain it from the execution of the bulk operation. Of course, since you specify the criteria to determine which documents are updated, you can find out which documents are updated from the results of a find query with the same criteria. as long as the documents don't change in between. During a multistage bulk operation, you might change what documents match the update.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, I saw you were right and abandoned it. I was just trying to avoid that find query.